# How do i test requests with digest authentication on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, hash, rspec-rails

Hope you're having a great day.

I'm new to security in Rails and I've come through a problem of authenticating a Digest request on tests in Rails. From the course I'm learning this from (which doesn't use tests), the Digest authentication provided by Rails is not really that much used, so there wouldn't be a necessity for it. But i still got curious on how to test it with RSpec, which led me to a lot of hours trying to do something that probably isn't supposed to be done.

Anyways, here's my dilemma, it seems to me that a Digest authentication needs two requests, where it can send some variables through the header (like "nonce" and "opaque") and another that receives some calculated stuff with the "failed" request header (like "cnonce" and "response").

Bellow is a code of a helper to make the second header before mocking the request again, which would then make a OK status. Unfortunately, there're some variables lacking (in the case, "cnonce" and "response"), and i have no idea where to find them. I tried finding methods in Digest related classes on Ruby and Rails, but none seem to make these calculations, although i feel like i'm not seeing something here.

```rb
class DigestHeaderWriter
  def initialize(header, user, password)
    @header = header
    @user = user
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    str_pieces = @header["WWW-Authenticate"].split(/\"/)
    { 
      "ACCEPT" => "application/vnd.api+json",
      "Authorization" => 
      "Digest username=\"#{@user}\","\
      "realm=\"#{str_pieces[1]}\","\
      "nonce=\"#{str_pieces[5]}\","\
      "uri=\"/kinds/1\","\
      "nc=00000001"\
      "algorithm=MD5"\
      "qop=auth"\
      "opaque=#{str_pieces[7]}"
    }
  end
end
```

OBS: forgive me the unused `password` variable, i thought i could calculate something with it.

Here is an example string array from the first response header, aka `str_pieces`:

```
[
  "Digest realm=",
  "Application",
  ", qop=",
  "auth",
  ", algorithm=MD5, nonce=",
  "MTY2MDY4NTQ5MTpiMmE3N2FhYWJlMTYwYmI3ZTM3YzZkY2VlMjcxZmEyOA==",
  ", opaque=",
  "5d5ba5ba4a787523d37a8ad54c64a8a9"
]
```

Bellow is the test on the spec archive:

```rb
  describe "GET /show" do
    it "renders a successful response" do
      kind = Kind.create! valid_attributes
      kind2 = Kind.create! valid_attributes2

      get "http://www.example.com/kinds/1", headers: header
      get "http://www.example.com/kinds/1", headers: DigestHeaderWriter.new(response.header, "Name", "secret").call

      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(response.body).to include valid_attributes[:description]
      expect(response.body).not_to include valid_attributes2[:description]
    end
  end
```

Basically it just stops at `expect(response).to be_successful`, and the header string just says that it's not an authorized request (401).

Maybe there's a whole other way to do it, either way i'm curious for a solution.